# If email subject line starts with certain values then do something

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

What is wrong with this line of code? Throws up Run-time error '13', Type mis-match.

```
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem

If mail.Subject Like "VEH" & "*" Or "MAT" & "*" Then
```

Trying to say if the subject of the email starts with "VEH" or "MAT", then do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for your `If` statement is:

```
If (mail.Subject Like "VEH*") Or (mail.Subject Like "MAT*") Then
```

The brackets are optional (`Like` operator has higher precedence than `Or`), but it's easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use VBA `LEFT` function here:

```
If UCASE(LEFT(TRIM(mail.Subject), 3)) = "VEH" OR UCASE(LEFT(TRIM(mail.Subject), 3)) = "MAT" Then

'' DO something here

End If
```

Comment: I would prefer this method. provided it is slightly modified :)

Comment: Yes you are right Siddharth! Need to trim the subject and add Ucase in order to avoid inconsistency of data. Answer is updated now.

Comment: ++ now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

If the emails are from different users then I wouldn't recommend using `Like` in such a scenario. If it is machine generated with fixed Subject then it makes sense.

**Reason**: `Like/Left` is case sensitive

**Example**:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim s As String

    s = "vehicle"

    If s Like "VEH*" Then
        MsgBox "Found a match"
    Else
        MsgBox "didn't find a match"
    End If
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim s As String

    s = "vehicle"

    If Left(s, 3) = "VEH" Then
        MsgBox "Found a match"
    Else
        MsgBox "didn't find a match"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Alternative**

For a search which is not case sensitive for example `Vehicle`, `vehicle`, `VeHiCle`, modify what @PareshJ posted.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim subj As String

    subj = "   Vehicle Number XYZ"

    If UCase(Left(Trim(subj), 3)) = "VEH" Then
        MsgBox "Found a match"
    Else
        MsgBox "didn't find a match"
    End If
End Sub
```

`Trim` trims the leading and trailing spaces and `Ucase` converts a string into uppercase.

**Edit**

If you still want to use `Like` then you may want to use this

```
Option Compare Text '<~~ For case insensitive

Sub Sample()
    Dim subj As String

    subj = "   Vehicle Number XYZ"

    If Trim(subj) Like "VEH*" Then
        MsgBox "Found a match"
    Else
        MsgBox "didn't find a match"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Caution:** `Option Compare Text` will also affect any other comparisons in the code.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care for a comment? Maybe I will get to learn something from you? If it is that you just don't like my face then it is ok... Don't bother... I can't help you there much :P